# Issue when adding effects on Div

Tags: css, material-ui

In the case I have on toggle button that will bring this "mini drawer" that has some chips,
[After pressing the Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8BHv.png)

The issue in this case is that this chips just POP on the screen and I need to add some animation like this Drawer http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer, I tried to add the transition and transform on CSS but It wont work

JS Part:

```
renderChip() {
console.log("1.30");

return this.state.listChip.map( (i, index) => (
    <Chip className="chips">
        {i.nome}
    </Chip>
    ));
}

toggleList() {
    this.setState({
        visivel: !this.state.visivel,
    });
      //  (this.state.visivel) ? document.getElementById("push").style.width = "0" : document.getElementById("push").style.width = "10px"};

}

render()
{
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div >
                    <div className="anchor">
                        <RaisedButton
                            label="Label before"
                            labelPosition="before"
                            primary={true}
                            onClick = {this.toggleList}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div id="push" className="anchorz" style={(this.state.visivel) ? styles.wrapper : styles.closed} >
                        {this.renderChip()}
                    </div>
            </div>

        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

CSS part:

```
position: fixed;
display: flex;
right: 0;
bottom: 110px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
z-index: 900;
transition: transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;*/
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
```